# GAE Datastore concurrency question

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, google-cloud-datastore

If two processes modify the same entity concurrently, but only modify *different* properties, can they potentially overwrite the changes made by the other process when calling `DatastoreService.put`?

**Process A:**

```
   theSameEntity.setProperty ("foo", "abc");
   DatastoreService.put (theSameEntity);
```

**Process B:**

```
   theSameEntity.setProperty ("bar", 123);
   DatastoreService.put (theSameEntity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible they'll overwrite each other's changes, since the entire entity is sent to the datastore ([serialized using protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write.html)) with each write (not just a diff).

You'll need to use [transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html) if you want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have observed this (though in my case the concurrent requests modified the same property).

I don't think transactions will help because they don't lock the datastore they guarantee, that the operations in the transaction will see the same data. I Would like to know if anyone has found a solution to this.